# getBoundingClientRect() returning wrong bottom value for a div element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have the following html and css code.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.image-slider {
    padding: 34px;
    width: 550px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.image-slider .images {
    display: block;
    margin: 14px 24px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="image-slider">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="Img1" class="images">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="Img2" class="images">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="Img3" class="images">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="Img4" class="images">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="Img5" class="images">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I try to print get the getBoundingClientRect() of my *image-slider* div, it returns the following object.

```
{ 
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 550,
    height: 96,
    top: 0,
    right: 550,
    bottom: 96,
    left: 0
}
```

The height and bottom value is **96**. But the actual height of the div turns out to be around 400px. Why is this happening? Am I missing out anything here?

**Update1**
I am basically trying to create an image viewer where left and right arrows appear on hovering on the left and right of the div. Please find my JS code. Due to the above issue, "Inside" only gets logged while hovering only on the top portion of the div.

```
const imageSlider = document.querySelector(".image-slider");
const coords = imageSlider.getBoundingClientRect();

imageSlider.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    if (!event) return;

    if (isMouseInsideTheImageSlider(event)) {
        console.log("Inside");
    }
})

function isMouseInsideTheImageSlider(event) {
    return event.clientX <= coords.right && event.clientX >= coords.left
        && event.clientY <= coords.bottom && event.clientY >= coords.top;
}
```

Comment: Please post your JS code.

Comment: @AsherMoshav Added my js code.

Comment: The height you are getting is 2x34 + 2x14 ie the margin and padding of parent and content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read the sizes of the element before the images are loaded, so the height is wrong. You should read the bounding rects after all images have loaded (move it inside the event listener or create some code to wait for all images to load).